# Azure DevOps AndroidSigning task does not sign APK

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, xamarin.android

i am in the process of setting up an automatic build using the pipelines in Azure DevOps. The pipeline seems to work fine but when i try to install the APK built through that pipeline i get a parsing error. I found out using the jarsigner tool that the APK hasn't even been signed. The AndroidSigning step doesn't show an error. In fact, i don't get any output from the apksigner tool despite the `--verbose` parameter being set by default.

My question is: How can i find out what is happening with the apksigner that causes the signing to fail?

Comment: At least provide repro steps for someone to get even close to find out what you are doing.

Comment: Would you please share the configuration information of your AndroidSigning Task and the debug log of the task?
Did you tried to sign your APK in your local with apksigner without azure devops pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution. Actually i found this a few days ago but forgot to answer.

If the apksigner does not return anything, this means that your Android SDK is missing files. Unfortunately the apksigner batch file does not return an error message to tell that the apksigner.jar (the actual signer) is missing.

Anyway in order to fix that i had to open the SDK Manager. The SDK Manager will automatically recognize that stuff is missing and offer you to download all the missing stuff to fix it.