# AZ Devops - The APK failed to install. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, signing

I have a Xamarin Android App that is not installing after being successfully built and signed in my Azure Pipeline. When I use Visual Studio for mac or Rider I am able to Archive For Publishing and get a runnable .apk :

when I download the successful build from the Azure Build Artifacts folder `/drop` and i drag on to the emulator I get the error:

```
The APK failed to install.
Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl810687574.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl810687574.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array
```

---

```
The Pipeline code looks like this:
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  droidOutputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)/Droid'
  iOSOutputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)/iOS'
steps:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(droidOutputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apksign: true
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'GuardianAngel360.keystore'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: 'XXXX'
    apksignerKeyPassword: 'XXXX'
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'GuardianAngel360'
    zipalign: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(droidOutputDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'specific'
    itemPattern: 'GA360-APP-Android'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your commands here  
      echo '******************ls -Step******************'
      ls $(droidOutputDirectory)   
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'ProductionAndroid'
    appSlug: 'GuardianAngel360/GA360-APP.Android'
    appFile: '$(droidOutputdirectory)/com.guardianangel360.ga360.apk'
    buildVersion: '1'
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'Here they are'
    destinationType: 'groups'
```

Here is the output from the AndroidSignTask above

```
26474765 META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro (OK - compressed)
26475012 META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/pom.xml (OK - compressed)
26476005 META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/pom.properties (OK - compressed)
Verification succesful
/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/32.0.0/apksigner sign --ks /Users/runner/work/_temp/GuardianAngel360.keystore --ks-pass pass:*** --ks-key-alias GuardianAngel360 --key-pass pass:*** --verbose /Users/runner/work/1/s/GeoFenceCandidate/GA360.Android/obj/Release/android/bin/com.guardianangel360.ga360.apk
Signed
Finishing: AndroidSigning
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754810/azure-devops-androidsigning-task-does-not-sign-apk